# Is it possible to export a dataset as an ANSI text file from Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

If I apply specific text formatting of header, body, and trailer to input data within Foundry via SQL, is there a way to export the output dataset as an ANSI text file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TEXT` output format in combination with concatenating your data to a single column and coalescing to a single partition. This output format doesn't support numeric types, so make sure to cast numeric columns as `string`:

```
CREATE TABLE `/path/to/your_output` USING TEXT AS 
    SELECT /*+ COALESCE(1) */ col1 || ' ' || cast (col2 as string) as result FROM `/path/to/your_input`
```

The resulting file should be available for download in the dataset details page:

[file_download_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoYh6.png)